# settings up logging in console script

Tags: python, logging

I have a python console script, which source I don't want to modify.

But I want to modify the logging which is done by the script and its libraries.

Examples:

- I want messages at level ERROR to be mailed to foo@example.com
- I want INFO messages of file foo.py to be ignored.
- I want to include the PID in the loggings messages.

The script uses this logger:

```
import logging
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
del(logging)
```

How can I configure the logging, if I don't want to modify the sources of the console script?

Comment: I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962525/configuring-the-logging-of-a-third-party-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load it using a wrapper script. In the wrapper, set the logging configuration as desired (e.g. `logging.basicConfig()`, or add logging handlers as desired), and then run the script.
If the script has a main function (look for `if __name__ == "__main__":` in the script), you can simply import the file and run the function:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(...)
import my_console_script
sys.exit(my_console_script.main())
```

If it doesn't have such a function, then simply importing it will run its contents (you can omit the `sys.exit()` call).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the existing lib logger, remove it and place your custom one.
See also here:
[Configuring the logging of a third party script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962525/configuring-the-logging-of-a-third-party-script/42386232#42386232)

Comment: Sounds like a dirty hack, but maybe there is no better solution.