# What is Python's site-packages directory?

Tags: python

The directory `site-packages` is mentioned in various Python related articles. What is it? How can I use it?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

`site-packages` is the *target directory* of manually built Python packages. When you build and install Python packages from source (using *distutils*, probably by executing `python setup.py install`), you will find the installed modules in `site-packages` by default.

There are standard locations:

- Unix (pure)<sup>1</sup>: `prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`
- Unix (non-pure): `exec-prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`
- Windows: `prefix\Lib\site-packages`

<sup>1</sup> *Pure* means that the module uses only Python code. *Non-pure* can contain C/C++ code as well.

`site-packages` is by default part of the Python *search path*, so modules installed there can be imported easily afterwards.

---

#### Useful reading

- [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) (for Python 2)
- [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/install/) (for Python 3)

Comment: location happened to be `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` on ubuntu

Comment: I've seen Gentoo systems with it in `lib64`!

Comment: does conda or pip install into site-packages, or just manually built packages?

Comment: The really interesting question is: Why this directory? Why not just install to `/usr/lib/python3.6`?

Comment: Is it safe to delete it? I always find that installing packages into a specific environment doesn't work, since it is found unser `site-packages`.

Comment: @MJimitater I wouldn't do that. I think it's probably better to create the virtual environment and specify --no-site-packages (Which SHOULD be the default but might not be in your situation for various reasons.)


`virtualenv --no-site-packages --python=/path/to/python/executable/python ENV_DIR_NAME`

Answer (score 86):

**When you use `--user` option with pip**, the package gets installed in user's folder instead of global folder and you won't need to run pip command with admin privileges.

The location of user's packages folder can be found using:

```
python -m site --user-site
```

This will print something like:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages
```

**When you don't use `--user` option with pip**, the package gets installed in global folder given by:

```
python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
```

This will print something like:

```
['C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages'
```

Note: Above printed values are for On Windows 10 with Anaconda 4.x installed with defaults.

Comment: Is it safe to delete it? I always find that installing packages into a specific environment doesn't work, since it is found unser `site-packages`.

Comment: You shouldn't this directory as it is managed by package manager.

Comment: But what about just deleting specific package inside of `site-packages`?

Comment: The `--user` parameter in python seems valid for Windows but not Linux. In Linux everyone is a user even `root` I think.

Answer (score 38):

*site-packages* is just the location where Python installs its modules.

There isn't any need to "find it". Python knows where to find it by itself, and this location is **always** part of the PYTHONPATH (sys.path).

Programmatically you can find it this way:

```
import sys
site_packages = next(p for p in sys.path if 'site-packages' in p)
print(site_packages)
```

Output:

```
'/Users/foo/.envs/env1/lib/python3.11.1/site-packages'
```

Comment: Probably easier to import site then site.getsitepackages()

Comment: Not all Python distributions have `site-packages`, and this will raise `StopIteration`. For instance, Debian (and Ubuntu) have `dist-packages` to install their distributed modules.

Comment: If you use virtualenv and do not inherit global packages then this will always work. I never code without a virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

On my [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7.9 Linux (a [Red Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) clone) it is found in `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/` and there isn't any need to include it in the PYTHONPATH variable.

Comment: I upvoted, unfortunately no other answer gives any hint for **per-user** python modules. I needed to change path from python3.9 -> python3.11 for newer version. It would be much nicer to get this programmatically though.

Answer (score -2):

According to [here](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html):

> A Python installation has a site-packages directory inside the module
> directory. This directory is where user installed packages are
> dropped.

Though it doesn't explain **why the word *site* is chosen**, it explains **what this directory is meant for**.

Comment: That link is from 2009; would you of anything newer, and clear and concise ?

Comment: @denis On the bottom left of that link, it says `v:latest`. Maybe it is latest.

Comment: ["Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging" is no longer maintained"](https://github.com/python/pythondotorg/issues/268) ...  the bottom of the ".../latest/..." URL page shows copyright 2009. Something on `https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/` would be a more recent reference.