# ImportError: No module named 'cplex' Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, cplex

I am trying to run python scripts on a HPC machine (RedHatEntrepriseServer). CPLEX module is already installed by adminastrators but I still have this error in importing cplex module in python.

`ImportError: No module named 'cplex'`

I know it is common error and I found that I may need to update PYTHONPATH variable with cplex home directory, but I can't find this home directory. Does anyone have an idea or suggestion to solve this problem?!

Many thanks!

Comment: refer to '~/.bashrc'

Comment: use the command `updatedb` and `locate`

Comment: @danche: can you please detail what I can add in '~/.bashrc' file?

Comment: @skr: How can I use the commands? ( `locate cplex` doesn't give any output)

Comment: @Betty `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:cplex path`

Comment: @danche : Thank you for the command, but I don't know and can't find cplex path...

Comment: @Betty 1st you have to do `updatedb` command then do `locate cplex` command

Comment: @skr: `updatedb` returns
 this message `updatedb: can not open a temporary file for '/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db' ` (I am a beginner and occasional user of Linux and I don't know what it does mean exactly). Thanks!

Comment: @Betty you have to be root/super user while running `updatedb`.

Comment: @skr: unfortunately, I don't root rights... thank you for the feedback anyway!

Comment: @Betty Try find command `find  / -iname "cplex"` only problem is it will take time.

Comment: @skr: Even it took a quite long time, I was able to find the proper cplex directory. Thank you!

Comment: @Betty happy i could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to skr and danche comments, here is how I solved the problem:

I looked for cplex location by using this command:

```
find / -iname "cplex"
```

Then I updated the `PYTHONPATH` variable with this location:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/local/software/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/python/2.6/x86-64_linux
```

I updated my `.bashrc` file with last command so each time I log in it is set automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is a perfectly reasonable solution here. Using `PYTHONPATH` has advantages, such as allowing you to easily switch between multiple versions of the CPLEX Python API. However, another option would be to ask your system administrator to install the cplex module. My guess is that they installed CPLEX Optimization Studio, but they did not actually install the CPLEX Python API into the system's default Python interpreter using the `setup.py` script (that is an optional step that would need to be performed separately). See the relevant documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html). Yet another option would be for you to setup your own Python environment using `virtualenv` (see, for example, [here](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)).

Comment: the administrators have already installed cplex module but the access to cplex directory was hidden. Thank you for the additional information!

Comment: Based on the path you're using in your `PYTHONPATH` the cplex module has *not* been installed using the `setup.py` script. Under normal circumstances, we would expect to see a [site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384639/what-is-pythons-site-packages-directory) directory in the path. The COS installer copies the files on to the hard-drive, but it does not put them in the Python search path. If `setup.py` had been used, then you would not need to set `PYTHONPATH`. At any rate, I'm glad you found a solution.