# Can't import libtorrent from Python 3.8.7

Tags: python, macos, python-3.8, libtorrent

so i am trying to import libtorrent from python file to make some code that download a torrent, but when I import it, it returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myUser/Documents/someDirectory/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import libtorrent
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libtorrent.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libtorrent.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03
        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libtorrent.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03
```

I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.6. Thank you, it would help a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that shared library was built for MacOS, and your version of MacOS in specific?

Comment: The libtorrent is installed builtin from the macOS, and idk how to check it, can i reinstall it for the MacOS and does the libtorrent support MacOS? Thanks

Comment: The header 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03 suggests this is an [ELF, 64 bit, little endian, *Linux*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header) file.

Comment: I see, so can i reinstall it for the macos version?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I don't install it, it just in there.

Comment: [``libtorrent`` is not part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html), and [``site-packages`` is only used for additional libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384639/what-is-pythons-site-packages-directory). Even if you did not explicitly install ``libtorrent``, you at least did so by extension of installing some lobrary that needs it.

Comment: So, can i reinstall it?