# How does the `j` suffix for complex numbers work? Can I make my own suffix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

I know what are complex numbers and how they mathematically work, but **how is it done for python to *know* it's complex just by putting a `j` after a digit ?**

```
>>> j
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
>>> 1*j
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
>>> 1j
1j
>>> 1j**2
(-1+0j)
```

## Can I make my own suffix, let's say `p` (for strictly positive) ?

Could I do something working like this ?

```
>>> ... some weird stuff here ...
>>> p
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
>>> 1*p
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
>>> -1p
1p
>>> 0p
1p
>>>
```

Comment: `j` is a part of the language definition, just like, e.g., `0x`. No, you cannot make your own suffix.

Comment: The `j` is recognized by Python's parser, exactly the same way that quote marks are recognized as the start of a string, or digits are recognized as part of a number.  The only way to add another such feature would be to edit Python's source code and recompile it.  Defining a function or class (`P(x)`, perhaps) would be a much more reasonable way to accomplish this.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is built into Python's grammar, just like the decimal point is, or the `e` in scientific notation (`1e10` etc.). The `j` makes a numeric literal imaginary.

Python does not allow you to change this. That doesn't mean you *can't*--you could amend the grammar--but then the language is no longer Python.

The closest approximation allowed in Python would be by implementing an operator.

```
>>> class StrictlyPositive:
    def __rmatmul__(self, number):
        return abs(number)


>>> p = StrictlyPositive()
>>> -1@p
1
```

But you have to be careful of operator precedence when doing stuff like this. Why not just use the builtin `abs` directly?